# Cron Job with PHP or Python

Tags: php, python, cron

I need cron job which fetch data from wsdl and store in database periodicly.How can I implement it in singleton to be sure no new instance created before latest ended?

I used file to store is cron job running or not,but I think better way should be exist.In java we can run Jar as daemon ,so it can controller to be singleton and never be kill(if killed,a new instance will created).How to implement it with out file in PHP or Python?

Comment: only other replacement:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [semaphores](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) if you do not like the pid file lock, even though that is a common practice. Also, I would suggest using [flock/fcntl](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html) instead of pid lock files. I think that would be quite good for you.

As for bash lock file practices right from the cron job, you could look at a good existing practice  in here:

```
#!/bin/sh

lockfile="/tmp/cron_rsync.lock"
if [ -z "$flock" ] ; then
  lockopts="-w 0 $lockfile"
  exec env flock=1 flock $lockopts $0 "$@"
fi
```

Comment: How to be sure one instance exist in all situations?

Comment: I think lockfile is not that bad. Not sure why you are so much against it.